# Networking two PCs that are connected to two routers which are connected to a master router

Tags: networking

I'm trying to connect two PCs that are connected to two routers which are connected to a master router.
To put it in a more simple way :

I have a master router (R1) that's connected to the internet.
I have another router (R2) connected to this master router (R1) via a LAN-To-LAN cable.
I have a third router (R3) connected to the router (R2) via a LAN-To-WAN cable (LAN on the side of R2 and WAN on the side of R3, I plugged the cable on the WAN port of R3 because all my LAN ports are occupied by my PCs).

So naturally my PCs that are connected to R2 (also via its LAN port) cannot detect the PCs that are connected to the router R3.

Is there any way to make it possible for these PCs to be in the same local network or to see each other?
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you also connect R2 by LAN-To-LAN and disable its DHCP server capability?

Comment: I agree . I would hook up R3 the same as R2, and then the computers can see each other.

Comment: @harrymc do you mean to connect R2 to R3 via LAN-To-LAN? If that's so then I can't, all the LAN ports on R3 are occupied. And R3 cannot be hooked directly to R1 because they are too far from each other.

Comment: You can use a small switch on R3 to expand the number of ports on R3 and then hook it up LAN to LAN to R2.

Comment: @John So if I use a switch on R3 I will have more LAN ports and then I'll be able too hook R2 to R3 via LAN-To-LAN and that way all computers on both routers will see each other, right?
Do I have to disable DHCP servers on both of these router and leave it enabled only on R1? And after disabling DHCP servers, will R1 and R2 still be able to emit wifi with no problems?

Comment: When you have one network, you should only have one DHCP server to avoid addressing conflicts. So yes, on R3 turn DHCP off.

Comment: @John wait, disable DHCP on both R2 and R3 and not only R3, right?

Comment: Just have one DHCP server on your network. R1 may be preferable if it is your main network router.